# How to display the age using php and Html

Tags: php

[image: how can i put the age inside the table please]

```
$dob=new DateTime($row[DOB]);  // Create a date object from the DOB field
          $age=$cd->diff($dob);          // Find the difference between the 2 dates
          echo $age->format(" Age:%y Years %m Months %d Days");  // Display the years, months and days
               echo"<td>".$row[$age]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row[WEIGHT]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[UNIT_WEIGHT]."</td>";
```

Comment: what is you question actually, because your showing some screenshot with ages

Comment: thanks Ravi but I got the answer, it was actually to put the age above in the table according to their respective row.but can i ask you if i were to display the search result on the html page itself .how can i do it?there are links but i tried its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider describing your problem better, but as far as I understood this is the answer you might be looking for.

You use 'echo' for the age output prior to the HTML table's row output.
You should use the format function call in the required cell.
Check the following code:

```
$dob=new DateTime($row[DOB]);  // Create a date object from the DOB field
$age=$cd->diff($dob);          // Find the difference between the 2 dates
echo "<td>".$age->format("%y Years %m Months %d Days")."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row[WEIGHT]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[UNIT_WEIGHT]."</td>";
```

Another note, usually age is year-based only.
So instead of:

> Age - 15 years 10 months 24 days

You might want to show only the years

> 15 (years)

in this case simply update the date object format's parameter.

```
$age->format("%y");
```